# Changing class styles dynamically without a loop

Tags: javascript, css, dhtml

Is it possible to change the style of a class via JavaScript without looping through existing elements which have that class applied to them? Since my page uses a lot of DHTML, this method would prove ineffective when creating elements.

I've searched and have only found the answers "no" and "loop", but I feel that the styleSheet object must be able to do something along these lines. If not, however, I will accept that, but first I want to ask here where people are most likely to know the final answer.

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Can you define a different class, and add/remove it as necessary? Unfortunately you cannot modify CSS style declarations from JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add style rules to your stylesheets dynamically:

IE: [addRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358796%28VS.85%29.aspx)
Others: [insertRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/stylesheet.insertRule)

Comment: That's useful. Is there a way to change properties of elements individually, or is this as close as it gets?

Comment: You can access, change and/or remove all the rules in a stylesheet, but you'll have to write browser-specific code, sadly. Look at `document.styleSheets[0].rules` and `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules`.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery, with this one line:

```
 $('.className').css("attrib", "value");
```

It will change the value of all elements with class = className.

Refer: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: I'd prefer not to use jQuery for learning purposes. Also, that seems that it'd only affect existing elements as the loop method would.

Comment: Indeed; in fact, this will loop under the hood.

Comment: _It'd only affect existing elements..._ Did not get you there, some elaboration will be welcome.